Should I expect a call from my future boss after signing the offer?
I live in Germany and I have recently landed a job at some bigger US tech company for a full remote position, which I am quite happy about. I will be starting soon and some 2-3 months ago I had a quite busy time talking to my future boss in interviews. I think it was a good match also on the personal level and we even had some nice chat after it was clear that I have passed the interviews. Then things moved ahead and my only point of contact became the recruiter.
Now I am somewhat surprised that I haven't heard of my future boss after the interview/offer phase. In my previous jobs at German companies, it was quite common practice to receive a personal call from the future boss shortly after signing the offer, where they would send out congratulations and have a quick chat with me.
Now I am seeing different explanations for this:

There is a cultural difference and this is not a common thing for US companies. Maybe for some reason they may not even be allowed to call me, but that seems unlikely to me.
This is a first subjective change I need to cope with, considering it is a full remote position: so far I haven't met any person from my future workplace, nor seen any office. I may be underestimating how the missing "physical" interaction influences my overall perception. Of course this doesn't change the fact that I didn't get a call, but maybe I would not have even noticed after a personal interview.
It is just a unfortunate situation that I'm expecting my future boss to call me while for them everything is settled (which my recruiter, with whom I do communicate regularly, already confirmed). They may simply get in touch with me when it's the right time.

What are your opinions about this? Is it common in US tech companies for the boss to call their future employees after an offer got through? Thanks for your inputs!

No, it's not common at all.

I would not say it's common for Germany either. It's great if it happens, but I would not expect it.

@JoeStrazzere Not surprising but unfamiliar. That's why I was wondering if my feelings about the situation may be tainted. After reading the comments/answers this might be the case.

Note that your boss would have to manage around a significant timezone difference


It is just a unfortunate situation that I'm expecting my future boss to call me while for them everything is settled (which my recruiter, with whom I do communicate regularly, already confirmed). They may simply get in touch with me when it's the right time.

That's it. People are busy, and they are not going to pick up the phone unless there is a specific reason to do so.
There is also nothing wrong with you calling or e-mailing your boss, if you have specific concerns, questions, or things that need to be arranged. Note the word "specific" here: the communication needs to have some purpose and not just be chit-chat.
In your case, you can simply ping them with a question like.

Hey boss, I'm looking forward starting my new job with you on XXX date. I just wanted to check if everything is still on track and what specifically I can do to make the transition and onboarding as smooth and efficient as possible.


I would think there's nothing wrong with a short, polite, positive e-mail to your boss along the lines "great that we will be working together, looking forward". As an incoming employee, and especially remote, you want to remain on your boss' radar, and a short message "happy I'm joining" is culturally accepted and normal. I would keep it brief though - as post says, busy people.

I think your suggested ping might risk annoying the boss, because it requires a response. Make it something that doesn't need any feedback.

I'd stick to a polite email rather than a phone call. Maybe a CC to the recruiter if you're really worried.

I wouldn't say it's expected for them to call you.
Look at it from their side: the applicant has spent a long time part of the hiring process, the contract is signed, everyone's aware of the start date. What else is there to do before you start?
There might be some practical questions (e.g. what laptop OS you prefer) but overall, there's no need for them to ping you if they're happy waiting for your start date.
That's not particularly a remote thing, or a US thing. I generally haven't been contacted by my reporting manager after the interviews and before my start date.

I wouldn't expect a call just to say "well done". Maybe an e-mail, but neither would I worry if all your communication is with the recruiter. And again maybe some communication as you get closer to your start date about the mechanics of onboarding, but again I wouldn't worry if that all came from the recruiter.
That said, if there's stuff it would actually be useful for you to talk to your future manager about, there's nothing stopping you setting up that meeting.

The most likely calls AND emails you'll receive, in order of likelihood:

HR / Benefits.  If you haven't already, you may be asked to fill out a formal job application.  Additionally, HR may contact you with paperwork to sign for form W-4, form I-9, employee handbook, identity verification.  There are also health, vision, dental, 401K and possibly life insurance benefits you'll have to address before or near your start date.
IT - may contact you for provisioning of hardware, software, accounts, and your desk telephone.
Reception / facilities.  Stuff to do with your seating situation, if you work in the office.
Management / peers.  A manager or above may contact you to congratulate you.  This is nice, but don't expect it.  One caveat here is any conversation about specific skills you bring to the team, with respect to any actual current challenge the department may be facing.  It's a potential "red alert" if someone tries to pump you for solutions before your start date.  You may be eager to impress, but avoid sharing too much of your time and expertise for free, because you could be setting a precedent that will not serve you well.


I wouldn`t worry if you have done all the offer / contract paperwork against HR and have a starting date.
There may be a contact regarding equipment delivery, if company providing any.
